# find first value matching the substring

Tags: regex, string, awk

The 9th column has multiple values separated with ";". I am trying to find first occurrence of string after "name_id" in column $9 of a tab limited file - the first line of the file looks like this eg.

```
1   NY  state   3102016 3102125 .   +   .   name_id "ENSMUSG8868"; trans_id "ENSMUST00000082908"; number "1"; id_name "Gm26206";ex_id "ENSMUSE000005";
```

There are multiple values separated by";" in 9th column.  I could come up with this command that pulls out the last "ENSMUSE000005" id

```
sed 's|.*"\([0-9_A-Z]\+\)".*|\1|' input.txt | head
```

Can it be done with regex in awk? thanks a lot!

Comment: is `ENSMUSG8868` your desired output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo $x |awk -F';' '{split($1,a," ");gsub(/"/ ,"" ,a[10]);print a[10]}'
ENSMUSG8868
```

Where x is your line.

Based on OP's comments :

```
echo $x |awk -F';' '{split($1,a," ");gsub(/"/ ,"" ,a[10]);print a[1],a[10]}'
1 ENSMUSG8868
```

Comment: This works perfect! Thanks. Is there anyway to output the first column along with this? right now I am doing it in two steps by running a separate awk command. will combining these possible given two different delimiters.

Comment: what is your expected output including 1st column ?

Comment: `1 ENSMUSG8868`

Comment: This is such a neat and perfect solution! Thanks a lot! :)